# When a bond is formed between an electophile and a nucleophile, they both lose energy and become more stable right?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond

[image]

This is a section from clayden's organic chemistry textbook. I do not understand why it says energy gain and not energy loss

Comment: I agree, that doesn't make sense. If you looked at the enthalpy, I would say those bond-forming processes are exothermic, therefore an energy loss by the *system* (reactants->products).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the picture provided, it seems just a matter of language choice. When energy is lost, it is gained somewhere else because of conservation of energy. So a change in energy corresponding to a gain is at the same time a loss elsewhere. The author of that diagram could have used interchangeably *energy loss* without loss of meaning.